# Componente switchery não funciona em uma PartialView - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tendo problemas com o data-plugin switchery (Componente Remark bootstrap) que não quer funcionar em partialviews. O interessante é que se ele ficar dentro de uma view normal, funciona perfeitamente, mas quando colocado dentro de uma janela modal (#modalGenerica) aberta por uma partialview, não funciona:

Em uma view Normal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em uma PartialView (Problema):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.ContatoTipo.ContatoTipoViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_ContatoTipo";
}

<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body container-fluid pt-10 pl-15 pr-15">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <vc:summary />
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label asp-for="Descricao" class="control-label">Descrição</label>
                        <input asp-for="Descricao" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Descricao" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="example">
                    <div class="float-left mr-20">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="inputiCheckBasicCheckboxes" data-plugin="switchery"
                               checked />
                    </div>
                    <label class="pt-3" for="inputBasicOn">On</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $('#mycheckbox').switchery({
        switcheryParent: $('#modalGenerica')
    });

</script>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

}
```

Eu tentei inicializá-lo na partialview, mas não funcionou. Não sei se existe mesmo a propriedade switcheryParent...

```
<script>
    $('#mycheckbox').switchery({
        switcheryParent: $('#modalGenerica')
    });

</script>
```

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?
Um abraço a todos e o obrigado!

Comment: Não é por que a sua partial não herda a mesma master page das views que por sua vez incluem o js e css do componente?

Comment: Onde eu poderia alterar para fazer a herança @LeandroAngelo?